# Hair collision problem in Blender 2.8

Tags: hair

I have been trying hair dynamics in Blender 2.81. I am using a hair particle system on my mesh. I need the emitted hair to interact and collide with the mesh. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: You can watch this YouTube video it's for you. That what you need.
https://youtu.be/Lfo9ISZg1BI

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with this.
Here you have some advice: [How do I stop hair particles going through the body and the head?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62122/how-do-i-stop-hair-particles-going-through-the-body-and-the-head)
Hair dynamics works, but not perfectly. In faster speed of the object, some strands always will go trough the mesh. Also there is a bug in Blender 2.8. - When the quality step (hair dynamics) is above 1, hair explodes. So, don't use this verison if you want some collisions.