# How to I set up hair particle collision?

Tags: particles

Youtube and the rest of the internet all have different answers for this... I was just wondering how I make my hair collide with my mesh instead of falling through it in 2.8.

Comment: Apparently, there's a bug. Can anyone confirm this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159163/hair-collision-problem-in-blender-2-8