# How to prevent the rigging hair pass through the body, object or mesh while animated?

Tags: animation, mesh, collision

Greeting...
I never find this problem solution for 2 years... can some one help me? Please? or blender dont have way to do this?...
HERE THE FILE :
[image]
[image: Preview The hair trought the body]

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62122/how-do-i-stop-hair-particles-going-through-the-body-and-the-head?rq=1 If not,  could you specify what's different?

Comment: That was using hair particle system not using bone on that hair (rigging hair)