# Hair passing through emitter at high velocities

Tags: particles, physics, hair

I'm working on an animation involving a hair system on a fairly angular object, the goal is to use hair dynamics to make the object "shake" like a dog, and have the hair behave accordingly.

Everything works quite well, but at particularly high velocities during the shaking motion, the hair clips through the mesh, revealing the emitter. I have tried the solutions proposed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56473/84336) & [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62133/84336). I haven't seen great results with either solution, but the latter is especially destructive and will often cause my hair system to completely flip out..

The clipping:
[image]

Best solution so far has been to bump up the stiffness of the hair like crazy, but I still have some clipping occurring at the highest velocities, I'm unsure what else to try, any other options or directions would be appreciated. Maxing out the damping / clamping obviously stops the clipping from occuring but this virtually freezes the hair, ideally the hair is still quite flowy / bouncy. Hair dynamics settings included below:

[image: Settings 1] [image: Settings 2]

Answer (score 0):

Hair Dynamics > collisions > Quality > set it to a value like 5 or higher

Cache > cache step > set it to a higher value like 2 or 3 if your movements are fast

always bake the cache for your animation .

if your problem solves don't forget to  like and accept this answer