# How do I fix hair collision on simulations

Tags: animation, particles, physics

[image]

The selected mesh do have the particle system and the body is a physics collision.
I think every one can see the problem

Comment: Related: [How do I make hair collide with a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27219/2217)