# Collision Object for particle system

Tags: particles, collision

The hair you see in the picture is created with a particle system on a vertex group. The hat is a separate object. Is there any way to make the hat a collision object so that the hair stops when it touches it?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling hair dynamics and then pressing play animation? Other than that you would need to set the hat to rigid or soft body (depending in the effect you want) and setting collisions to mesh.

Comment: See this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29232/49984